# How to fix editable input text field for Radio group button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my problem: when I select the other radio button, it shows input text but text can not be edited. That means 'other' word is fixed and can not be edited . How to make the text editable?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  <RadioGroup onChange={this.onChangeRedio} value={this.state.value}>
              <Radio  value="Father">Father</Radio>
              <Radio value="Mother">Mother </Radio>
              <Radio   value="Husband ">Husband </Radio>
              <Radio  value="Wife">Wife </Radio>
              <Radio value="Brother">Brother </Radio>
              <Radio  value="Sister">Sister </Radio>

              <Radio  value="other"> Other
        {this.state.value === "other" ? <Input value={this.state.value}  style={{ width: 100, marginLeft: 10 }} placeholder="Other" type="text" /> : null}
              </Radio>
</RadioGroup>
```

Here is my js code:

```
onChangeRedio = (e) => {
  console.log('radio checked', e.target.value);
  this.setState({
     value: e.target.value,
  });
}
```

Comment: You need an `onChange` in that `Input` [Source](https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your input is, what is known as, an [uncontrolled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

You're providing a value attribute, but neglected to provide an onChange handler that'll update the `value` state with the input's value. This is what makes it an "uncontrolled input".

The solution is to simply add an `onChange` handler that'll update your `value` state.

For example,

```
<Input type="text"
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.handleOtherChange}
/>

handleOtherChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}
```

---

Another issue exists, since your current logic only displays the input field when the `value` state property is equal to 'other'. This is problematic, because as soon as you type something into the input it'll disappear.

As a solution, lets make a smarter conditional that says "if the value state property is not one of our presets, or it is "other", show the input.

I'd suggest moving your radio presets into an array, then rendering the `Radio` components using that array; then you can write a function that says `if state value is not in radio array, return true; else return false`, which you can use to determine whether or not to render the input field.

---

**To learn more about your issue, consider taking a look at the following React documentation:**

Uncontrolled components - https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Controlled components - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: sir i added handleOtherChange function but that other word is fix ..can not editable

Comment: Please see my updated answer, which sets `value` state to the `event.target.value` passed through onChange handler.

Comment: sir here condition is "this.state.value=="other" " when value =other .its show input field .. so when i type the text that input field is hidden ...bcz condition is wrong here .i need without condition when i click othe radio button show input field and can be type ..plz help me sir